# Чем интерфейс IEnumerable<T> отличается от IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#

Собственно не могу понять основное отличие и для чего они были добавлены.

Comment: IEnumerable является родителем IQueriable, это означает, что он умеет всё тоже самое что IEnumerable  плюс немного ништяков, связаных с СУБД. Открываем msdn - там всё перечислено: Expression, ElementType, Provider и ещё пара тройка методов.

Comment: Для чего - msdn "Provides functionality to evaluate queries against a specific data source wherein the type of the data is not specified." - Предоставляет функциональные возможности для вычисления запросов к конкретному источнику данных, в котором тип данных не указан.

Comment: Понравилось - хабр http://habr.com/ru/post/256821/ - Принципы работы IQueryable и LINQ-провайдеров данных

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Основным различием между `IEnumerable<T>` и `IQueryable<T>` является то, что интерфейс `IQueryable<T>` позволяет работать с удаленными источниками данных. Например, если у вас есть некоторая база данных и вы хотите выгрузить некоторое отфильтрованное подмножество данных, то при использовании `IEnumerable<T>.Where()` будут загружены все записи из таблицы, а затем произведена фильтрация, а при использовании `IQueryable<T>.Where()` фильтрация будет произведена на уровне базы данных, а загружены будут только искомые записи.

подробнее [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252785/what-is-the-difference-between-iqueryablet-and-ienumerablet)