# Рефакторинг обработки IEnumerable и IQueryable (C#)

Tags: c#, база-данных, ienumerable

Имеются два объекта с типами **IEnumerable** и **IQueryable**

Один используется для обработки перечислений внутри памяти приложения, другой для отправки запросов к БД

Добавляются два метода фильтрации (по одному для каждого типа)

```
private IQueryable<Employees> CreateEmployeeQuery(IQueryable<Employees> query, EmployeeFilter employeeFilter)
{
    var query = query.Where(w => employeeFilter.EmployeeId == null || w.Id == employeeFilter.EmployeeId);
    
    return query;
}
```

```
private IEnumerable<Employees> CreateEmployeeQuery(IEnumerable<Employees> employees, EmployeeFilter employeeFilter)
{
    var employees = employees.Where(w => employeeFilter.EmployeeId == null || w.Id == employeeFilter.EmployeeId);
    
    return employees;
}
```

Хотелось бы уточнить, как будет влиять на производительность и есть ли какие-то подводные камни при использовании подхода: выделить один метод и делать преобразования .AsQueryable() или .AsEnumerable()

И какой метод в таком случае практичнее оставить? Или какие доводы есть в пользу каждого из методов?

Comment: Поможет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/959449/%d0%a7%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81-ienumerablet-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82-iqueryablet?rq=1?

Comment: А тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252785/what-is-the-difference-between-iqueryablet-and-ienumerablet вообще с картинками

Comment: Не совсем то, что хотелось бы получить. Чем отличается, я вроде бы разобрался. А вот интересно в чём есть свои особенности при преобразовании. Может какая-то информация теряется или затраты на преобразования дороже получаемого эффекта от сокращения кода. Есть у кого-нибудь личный жизненный опыт по данному вопросу?

Comment: В Remarks https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.asenumerable?view=net-7.0 всё чётко написано. Документацию нужно почитать